# Creating more than one object in Python without using a prefix name for an object

Tags: python-3.x, oop

If I run this code:

```
class A():
   def __init__(self): 
      print(self)
a = A() 
b = A()
```

output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x7fe4378b4b70>
<__main__.A object at 0x7fe4371ce198>
```

Then from the output, I can tell that each object will reserve its own location in memory.

But if I run the following without giving a name to the objects:

```
class A():
   def __init__(self): 
      print(self)
A() 
A()
```

output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x7f34e5840b70>
<__main__.A object at 0x7f34e5840b70>
```

Then the output will be the same! How would I get different objects without assigning each object to a named variable?

Comment: `A(), A()` would create an anonymous tuple with 2 unique objects. Do you need to access these objects after they've been created?

Comment: I want to create more than one object with a for loop by just using A() inside a for loop. Yes, I need to access these object after I create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow on from your comment, how about using a list?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self): 
        print(self)

objects = [A() for _ in range(5)]
```

output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x0105F890>
<__main__.A object at 0x01190830>
<__main__.A object at 0x011908B0>
<__main__.A object at 0x011908D0>
<__main__.A object at 0x011908F0>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!